# Get all elements except ones from a certain class?

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have a JavaScript function that uses `getElementsByClassName("apples")` to find everything in the class `apples`.  My problem is that I can't seem to find a way to fetch every element **not** in the class `apples`.  Is there any helper functions in JavaScript that might allow me to do this?   Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't do it with `getElementsByClassName`.

The easiest way on modern browsers would be to use:

```
document.querySelectorAll(':not(.apples)')
```

On older browsers you'd probably have to use `document.getElementsByTagName('*')` followed by a filtering operation to remove the unwanted elements.  This would probably be very slow.

Comment: If he's using `getElementsByClassName`, then I think the only browser that would support that but not `qSA` would be FF3.

Comment: ...oh wait. `:not()` isn't supported in IE8. Oh well.

Comment: @squint IE8 isn't a modern browser ;-)

Comment: Totally agree. Just that for a moment I thought the solution had a little wider support. But still, `gEBCN` isn't supported in IE8 either, so FF3 is the only loss. :-)